# I want to split the data in different sheets in a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, overflow

I am trying to **automate a spreadsheet to transfer data from one sheet to Multiple Sheets** **depending upon the Region**. there are more than **39 thousand lines** and I am getting an error as `"Run-time Error '6': Overflow"`.  Please can anyone help me and below is the code used. Thanks in ADVNCE

```
 Sub parse_data()
        Dim LR As Long
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim vcol, i As Integer
        Dim icol As Long
        Dim myarr As Variant
        Dim title As String
        Dim titlerow As Integer
        vcol = 14
        Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
        LR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
        title = "A1:AA1"
        titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
        icol = ws.Columns.Count
        ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
        For i = 2 To LR
            On Error Resume Next
            If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
                ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
            End If
        Next
        myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
        ws.Columns(icol).Clear
        For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
            ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
            If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
                Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
            Else
                Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
            End If
            ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & LR).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
        Next
        ws.AutoFilterMode = False
        ws.Activate
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your question should be tagged VBA not VB.NET - this is a big distinction especially where the size of data types are concerned.

In VBA (and VB6) a variable declared as `Integer` is an signed integer of 2 bytes meaning the range of values is `-32,768` to `32,767`

This means as soon as you try to put `32,768` into a variable declared as Integer it will cause the overflow error you are experiencing.

Changing this data type to a 'Long' should fix your issue as this has a range of `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`